# How can I sort other arrays when I have successfully sorted one of the three

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, double, swifty-json

I am looking to sort the ChangeArray so that it shows stocks in order from highest to lowest, I have accomplished this with the variable sortChange, but the BidArray and Stock Array do not correspond with the new data.  How Could I fix this. Thank you.

```
    var StockArray = [String]()
    var BidArray = [Double]()
    var ChangeArray = [Double]()




    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


//    @IBOutlet weak var StockSymbolLbl: UILabel!
//    @IBOutlet weak var BidSymbolLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getJSON()
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "StockHome", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()),forCellReuseIdentifier: "stockHome")
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
//        StockSymbolLbl.text = ""
//        BidSymbolLbl.text = ""


        }



    func getJSON(){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.stockURL)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
                let Symbol: String? = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["symbol"].stringValue
                let bid: String? = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Bid"].stringValue
                let change: String? = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Change"].stringValue
                print(change!)
                print(Symbol!)
                print(bid!)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
//                self.StockSymbolLbl.text? = "\(Symbol!)"
//                self.BidSymbolLbl.text? = "\(bid!)"
                    self.NumberofRows = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"].count

                    for i in 0...self.NumberofRows {
                        var stockcount = 0
                        stockcount += i
                        let Stock = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][stockcount]["symbol"].stringValue
                        let Bid = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][stockcount]["Bid"].doubleValue
                        let Change = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][stockcount]["Change"].doubleValue

                        self.StockArray.append(Stock)
                        print(Stock)
                        self.BidArray.append(Bid)
                        print(Bid)
                        self.ChangeArray.append(Change)
                        print(Change)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }



            }else{
                print("There was an error")
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return NumberofRows
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: StockHome = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stockHome", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StockHome

        if StockArray.count != 0{
            let sortChange = ChangeArray.sort(>)
            cell.symbolLbl?.text = StockArray[indexPath.row]
            let bid = BidArray[indexPath.item]
            let changeRate = ChangeArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.bidLbl?.text = "\(bid)" + " USD "
            cell.changeLbl?.text = "\(changeRate)" + " %"

        }

        print(self.StockArray)

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch ChangeArray[indexPath.row] {
        case let x where x < 0.0:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 59.0/255.0, blue: 48.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case let x where x > 0.0:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 76.0/255.0, green: 217.0/255.0, blue: 100.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case let x:
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44.0/255.0, green: 186.0/255.0, blue: 231.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your three arrays are independent and therefor do not guarantee to be in the same order.

What I would do is make struct with three values and append it to 1 single array which you can sort.

```
struct Stock {
     var symbol: String = ""
     var bid: Double = 0.0
     var change: Double = 0.0
}
```

Now you can rewrite the for loop in getJSON() like this:

```
for i in 0..<self.NumberofRows {
    let symbol = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][i]["symbol"].stringValue
    let bid = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][i]["Bid"].doubleValue
    let change = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][i]["Change"].doubleValue
    let stock = Stock(symbol: symbol, bid: bid, change: change)
    stockArray.append(stock)
}
```

Now you should be able to sort the 'StockArray' with this:

```
stockArray = stockArray.sort({
    return $0.change > $1.change
})
```

Slightly offtopic: some tips

Try to have the first character of variable names not capitalised, the first character of Classes/Enums/Structs capitalised. Every new word within the same variable name should be capitalised.

Secondly, try to rewrite your for loop to a for-each loop. [some documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html). This is much cleaner and makes `NumberofRows` no longer needed. And since everything is now in 1 array you can use `stockArray.count` in the `numberOfRowsInSection`

You can do the sort right before you call `tableView.reloadData()`, this way it is only sorted once, instead of every time a cell is loaded.

Lastly, try to use `if let` when working with JSON that might change, this way you are sure what you're treating as a Double is actually a Double. [Some documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: When I add the stockArray.append(Stock), I get an error because  the stockArray array is a only a string, how could I fix this?

Comment: change `var StockArray = [String]()` to `var StockArray = [Stock]()`